# Trying to access to a json field

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, fetch

I'm trying to print in a div a list of items inside the "ricette" field in a JSON field.

this is the JSON:

```
{
  "ricette": {
    "FRIGGITRICI": {
      "Alici": [
        [
          {
            "500": "scongelamento"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "60": "nada"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "Baccalà": [
        [
          {
            "500": "scongelamento"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "210": "immerso"
          },
          {
            "210": "cestello su"
          },
          {
            "30": "immerso"
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "GRIGLIA": {}
  }
}
```

and this is the function I'm using:

```
function updateJson(){
  fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/ld801')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((out) => {
    for (var i =0; i<out.length; i++){
      $("#showdata").append('alici= ', out[i].ricette.FRIGGITRICI.Alici[0][0].500,' <br> ');
    }
    console.log("JSON Update");
  })
}
```

the #showdata is correct (i'v tried to print some others JSON and it works).
how can I print a list of "ricette.FRIGGITRICi"? (in this case "Alici" and "Baccalà")

[JSON link](https://api.myjson.com/bins/zbfh5)

---

**EDIT**

whit this works
`out.ricette.FRIGGITRICI.Alici[0][0]['500']`

but it show "scongelamento"...

how can I show a list of "Alici, Baccalà"?

Comment: `out` doesn't appear to be an array?

Comment: `out` is an Object, not an Array - therefore it has no `length`

Comment: `out.ricette.FRIGGITRICI.Alici[0][0]['500']`.

Comment: ok it works, thanks:) now how can I print only the Items inside "FRIGGITRICE" without their  items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need this.

```js
fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/ld801')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((out) => {
    var l = Object.values(out['ricette']['FRIGGITRICI']);
    console.log(l);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
out.ricette.FRIGGITRICI.Alici[0][0]['500']
```

```js
let out ={
  "ricette": {
    "FRIGGITRICI": {
      "Alici": [
        [
          {
            "500": "scongelamento"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "60": "nada"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "Baccalà": [
        [
          {
            "500": "scongelamento"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "210": "immerso"
          },
          {
            "210": "cestello su"
          },
          {
            "30": "immerso"
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "GRIGLIA": {}
  }
}


console.log(out.ricette.FRIGGITRICI.Alici.concat(out.ricette.FRIGGITRICI.Baccalà));
```

Comment: Already tried... 
Do you know how to print a list of "Alici, Baccalà"?

Comment: @AndreaFavero both list or one "Alici, Baccalà" if one then `out.ricette.FRIGGITRICI.Alici`

Comment: both together plis

Comment: @AndreaFavero I have updated my answer please check is is works for you.